# 2 different results when expecting the same..why?

Tags: python

When running the code, please see below, input is ('Zoe', 14), I get as result 8, running the 'Finding Buckets' code in the Online Python Tutor also with ('Zoe', 14), where "def hash_string" is included, the result is 2 out 2, when that code finished, why? Or, in other words, does the other 2 defs causing that result?

In the 'Finding Buckets' code are 3 def. I exchanged the order of those def - the results are the same-does the order really does not matter?

```
def hash_string(keyword,buckets):
out = 0
for s in keyword:
out = (out + ord(s)) % buckets
return out

Online Python Tutor "Finding Buckets":

1 def hashtable_get_bucket(table,keyword):

2 return table[hash_string(keyword,len(table))]
3
4 def hash_string(keyword,buckets):
5 out = 0
6 for s in keyword:
7 out = (out + ord(s)) % buckets
8 return out
9
10 def make_hashtable(nbuckets):
11 table = []
12 for unused in range(0,nbuckets):
13 table.append([])
14 return table
15 table = [[['Francis', 13], ['Ellis', 11]], [], [['Bill', 17],
16 ['Zoe', 14]], [['Coach', 4]], [['Louis', 29], ['Rochelle', 4], ['Nick', 2]]]
17 print hashtable_get_bucket(table, "Zoe")


    def hashtable_get_bucket(table,keyword):
         return table[hash_string(keyword,len(table))]

    def hash_string(keyword,buckets):
         out = 0
         for s in keyword:
            out = (out + ord(s)) % buckets
         return out

   def make_hashtable(nbuckets):
         table = []
         for unused in range(0,nbuckets):
            table.append([])
         return table
```

Here the comment from the notes:

Function hashtable_get_bucket returns the bucket containing the given keyword, from the hash 
table, passed in as the first argument.

If you remember structure of a hash table, you will find out that it is composed of n buckets, one of 
which needs to be returned by the hashtable_get_bucket function. Index of the bucket, which 
would eventually contain the given keyword (in case the keyword will be present in the hash table), 
is computed and returned by already defined function hash_string.

The function hash_string will in turn take the keyword and number of buckets as its 
arguments. First argument (the keyword) is straightforward, since it was passed directly to 
hashtable_get_bucket function by its caller. The second argument (number of buckets) can be 
computed using len function on the hashmap (recall how hashmap is composed of n buckets).

Comment: Your Online Python Tutor probably told you in python Indention does matter. So please properly indent your code above.

Comment: No, the Tutor did not complain.

Comment: @user63888 You should probably find somewhere new to learn Python then, indentation is pretty important.

Comment: OK, i'll copy it from IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Both Functions do exactly the same. 
But in the online part `hash_string('Zoe', 5)` is called and not `hash_string('Zoe', 14)`

**Where dose the 5 come from?**

In line 2 there is:

```
hash_string(keyword, len(table))
```

with `len(tabel)` being `5`.

Comment: That is the number of the buckets, when running the code in the Tutor, after every step you see what happened. Therefore I wonder, why I got different results, expecting the same after running "def hash_string"

Comment: Yes, its the number of buckets. And the number of buckets is the argument to the hash_string function. `14` is just the value that is mapped to the keyword 'Zoe' and never used as an argument in the posted code.